# postgres partial index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with about 30 columns, column `a integer not null`, `b boolean not null` and `c integer not null` among them. And there is a query that is often run with `a = 2 and b is true and c = <something>`, i.e.

```
select * from my_table where a = 2 and b is true and c = 3215
```

The question is: should I include `a` and `b` columns in partial index, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_a_b_c
ON my_table 
USING btree  (a, b, c)
WHERE a = 2 AND b IS TRUE;
```

or should I not, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_a_b_c
ON my_table 
USING btree  (c)
WHERE a = 2 AND b IS TRUE;
```

In the first case `explain` outputs

```
"Index Scan using idx_my_table_a_b_c on my_table  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4007)"
"  Index Cond: ((b = true) AND (a = 2))"
```

and in the second `Index cond` part is absent

```
"Index Scan using idx_my_table_a_b_c on my_table  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4007)"
```

And by the way what does `Index cond` mean?

Comment: Please show us the `select` statement that corresponds to the explain output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SRY, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your index predicate is strict equality then there is no point in including the predicate columns in the index. Every index entry will have the same values for the columns and so won't    contribute to index lookup, they will only slow down inserts and lookups and bloat the index.

Answer (score 1):

My guess(!) is: in the first case (three column index) the column that needs to be evaluated in addition to the existing "index condition" is at the end of the index and therefor the index scan needs to evaluate the condition differently.

In the second case (single column index) the column that is used in the where condition (in addition to the already "indexed condition" is the leading column of the index and can be used more efficiently.

I would expect an index on `(c,a,b)` to behave the same way (note the different order compared to your three column index).

Comment: > I would expect an index on (c,a,b) to behave the same way...
And it does, unlike MySQL ;)